# Ubuntu 20.04 says password is incorrect for all users but one

Tags: login, password, users

My Ubuntu 20.04 laptop contains 4 users, 2 normal users and 2 administrators. Only the second administrator can login properly, all of the other users result in "Sorry, that didn't work" even after changing their password.

Second problem arises from the fact nearly all apps have dissapeared from second admin's app button on the bottom left, only the terminal and thai terminal appearing. I can still access firefox and other apps from the buttons on the left.

Problem arose after installing protonvpn. The first installation resulted in an error message trying to connect to any server, so I uninstalled it. Trying to reinstall the app caused the message "could not find protonvpn". I decided to try creating a new admin account and installing it there, which worked, but when I opened the newly installed protonvpn in a regular user, it said something along the lines of "Current key does not match user key" and asked for a password. None of the 4 user passwords worked and when I entered second admin the apps were gone and I could no longer access the other profiles, even after multiple reboots. I did not dare re-open the VPN afraid it might worsen the situation.

What could be happening here, and how could I solve this? I'm very new to linux, so if you can help, please use layman's terms.